# In AppleScript, how can I set one application to quit after another quits?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an AppleScript application which automatically saves my progress every 60 seconds. I'm writing an AppleScript application in which I open a specific document, set the index number of that document's window to 1 and open my autosave application.

I'd like to have the autosave app to quit when I press Command+Q to quit Pages.

For security reasons, I have omitted part of my file path, but here's my code: 
`tell application "Pages" to open "/Users/Documents/Home//Automator Article.pages/"
tell application "Pages" to set index of window "Automator Article.pages" to 1
tell application "Pages autosave" to launch`

Answer (score 0):

You can not trigger an Applescript from hitting ⌘Q to quit Pages. It is not possible.
One solution would be to trigger a script that quits Pages and then your "Pages autosave" applet (instead of pressing ⌘Q to quit Pages).

```
tell app "Pages" to quit
tell app "Pages autosave" to quit
```

You could trigger that script from the script menu in Pages, for instance.
Another option would be to add a menu to your "Pages autosave" applet that quit Pages and itself in turn.

Comment: Thanks jweaks! I'll try that out.

Comment: If it works, "accept" the answer for future reference.